# Microservices advice concern to share state between two services

Tags: java, redis, datasource, microservices

I am following the microservice architecture where we got two independed services

(UserService, OtherService)

UserService writes to it's own datasource (mysql and Redis)

Clients writing updates to UserService

In other hand Client's getting data from OtherService which need some user-state from UserService.

Latency and throughput of OtherService are very important.

few options:

1. UserService will update OtherService when state changes (than I break the domain responsibility of OtherService since it shouldnt maintenance users states
2. OtherService will ask UserService (via api) for the user states (adding lots of latency which is critical for me. I could cache but still.. not sure thats the right way)
3. having shared datastore while UserService write and OtherService reads.. breaking also the microservice principle when sharing same datasource

What do you guys think would be right to do?
Thank you,
ray.

Comment: You could have UserService expose some sort of observable interface where other services can register to be notified for UserService changes. it would still be the OtherService's job to fetch the relevant data from the UserService. In this way your coupling between the two services wouldn't be explicit and you'd allow for other service to implement the same pattern.

Comment: how would expose "some sort of obervable interface". the service using rest to speak with each other..

Comment: The UserService should have a subscribe endpoint which other interested services would call. They should provide their own callback endpoint where the UserService would send notifications of changes. When state changes the UserService notifies the subscribers that the event changed.  An even more general aproach would be to use an event bus where all services can publish events. See [this article](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/scaling-microservices-event-stream) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I liked the publish-subcribe idea but that means that each consumer going to maintain his own users's state datasource. otherService1,otherService2... each one going to hold it's own datasource(redis in my case).. isnt that crazy? what do you think. would be great if you answer this question and ill be able to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using a redundant read-only data on passive side and message queues for communication for those kind of scenarios. I mean having a user state table in your other service side and update it as the messages comes from your user service. It won't effect availability,performance and scalability of your OtherService. Dependency will be almost zero. The only possible problematic side of that approach could be the freshness of your user state data. By freshness problem I am talking about milliseconds generally. If that freshness problem is that important in your case then your best bet could be combining two services.

Comment: thanks for response. 1. ".. having a user state table in your other service side and update it.." what do you mean by table? additional datasource or ?  2. I dont have refresh requirement of milliseconds but of minutes.

Comment: 1. yeah you should have duplicate data but not all of it just the necessary ones for your other service. 2. then you should not have any problem with that approach

Comment: No prob to duplicate. but should I also create separate datasource for each otherService that need users Details data?

Comment: Normally data should be provided by your UserService through a "real service". there should be no redundant data. Every data owner should provide their data. At least if you want to have a "true" maintainable,sustainable microservice architecture. So if you need data from UserService you should consume it.  But in your case since your OtherService can't wait for UserService what I offered was a kind of hack. We are using exact same thing for one of our service which is highly consumed like almost million time in a day and can wait for other services to respond.

Comment: Btw if you can guarantee that you provide your data from UserService with a very low latency by using some tech. like  in memory database redis etc. then you still can use the "right" way. But since I saw there is "mysql" then latency always will be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think that option #2 on your list is the correct way of doing it. You haven't said anything about latency numbers in your question.

Generally MS architecture implies that you run on many 'machines/dockers' across multiple regions, any instance can born or die at any given moment, and if you are not running in the same data center then no matter what you do you'll get latency.

We (coming from big bloated enterprise apps) sometimes have a hard time to vertically break down application into logical functional pieces. Because of that, I think it's worth to consider taking out parts from UserService and OtherService and make yet another MS. Don't think that it will be too many MS's, companies have literally in mid-1000s of them and it works fine. Don't be afraid to do it outside the box.